# Como pegar o estado de um reducer dentro de um component com o React Native

Tags: react, react-native, redux

Olá, sou novato com React Native e estou tendo problemas pra conseguir passar o estado de um reducer para um componente que eu fiz. o mesmo está da seguinte forma:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

class Foo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const foo = !!this.props.isEnabled ? 'sim!' : 'não!';
        return <View><Text>{foo}</Text></View>
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    console.log(state);
    return { isEnabled: state.fooReducer.isEnabled }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Foo);
```

O redux está funcionando e eu consigo visualizar a mudança de estado a partir do `console.log()` que coloquei no `mapStateToProps` só não consigo passar esse estado para o componente e usálo para manipular o render.

O que preciso fazer para usar esse estado dentro do render?

Comment: E se você chamar o `mapStateToProps` dentro da função `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: Não entendi. Até onde eu sei, mapStateToProps é parte do redux... em teoria não tem como eu pegar isso la dentro do componentDidMount()

Comment: O seu `mapStateToProps` retorna o isEnabled que como você disse está funcionando, atribuindo o retorno do mesmo dentro `componentDidMount()` você, acredito eu, conseguirá utilizá-lo no `render()`

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo? de como usar isso?

Answer (score 1):

Teoricamente a parte do componente esta funcionando, você esta usando o *combine reducer*? Se não estiver não precisar especificar qual *reducer* está usando apos a *variavel estate*, `ex : state."REDUCER".variavel`.
Tenta acessar apenas o `state` pelo *console.log*, caso venha um valor não esperado pode ser alguma configuração do *redux* que não você setou errado ex a `store`, o *provider*, o *reducer* etc.

Comment: Estou sim usando o combineReducer e eu consigo dar um consórcio.log quando eu coloco ele dentro do mapStateToProps... Só que se eu tento um console.log dentro do componentWiilMount não aparece o console, mesmo que o do mapStateToProps apareça